# Cmake - change where the lib and include directories are for an externalproject and proper linking

Tags: c, cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.1 FATAL_ERROR)
project("soxy")

add_definitions(-std=c99)

include_directories(soxy)

# Includes
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(
    LibUV
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/libuv/libuv.git"
    GIT_TAG "v1.4.2"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND sh <SOURCE_DIR>/autogen.sh && ./configure --prefix=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    PATCH_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND "make"
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build
)

set( SOXY_SRC src/file_utils.c
     src/http_parser.c
     src/http_request.c
     src/path_utils.c
     src/string_utils.c
)

set( SOXY_HDR src/debug.h
     src/file_utils.h
     src/http_client.h
     src/http_parser.h
     src/http_request.h
     src/logger.h
     src/path_utils.h
     src/soxy_constantsh
     src/soxy.h
     src/string_utils.h
)

set( SOXY_BIN src/soxy.c )

add_executable(soxy ${SOXY_BIN})
add_dependencies(soxy LibUV)
```

Project structure:
    `/soxy`
    `/soxy/CMakeLists.txt`
    `/soxy/build/`

When I build the makefile and run make, the lib and include for the external project end up in /soxy, I'd like them to show up in /soxy/build/ and when it builds my project it doesn't setup the include right such that `#include <uv.h>` doesn't work and is an unresolved header file inclusion.

Comment: You should provide feedback to the answers you receive

Answer (score 1):

You are using `--prefix=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`. Try using `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, you are getting several things wrong.

- You usually don't need to define a list of header files.
- You are not telling anywhere to compile the files contained in the `SOXY_SRC` variable. You would compile them for example if you did `add_executable(soxy ${SOXY_BIN} ${SOXY_SRC})`.
- After `add_dependencies` you'll also need `target_link_libraries`.
- You should target "out of source" build. That is, you shouldn't have stuff like `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build`

So, try the following (I don't know the `ExternalProject_Add` command so I can only guess the behaviour). Modify two lines of `ExternalProject_Add` like this:

```
BUILD_IN_SOURCE 0
PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/LibUV
```

And add:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/LibUV)
```

You'll probably need also

```
link_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/LibUV)
```

Ideally the include directory of LibUV is different from the library directory, take a look to what your 
`ExternalProject_Add` effictively does.

As said before, you'll probably need a `target_link_libraries(soxy uv)` or something similar, depending on the generated library name